# Open lightbox when click on link

Tags: php, jquery, lightbox

I am looking for solution to open lightbox ( images ) when click on the link.

Example:

```
<a href="">View Gallery</a>
```

Here is my working image code with lightbox within foreach loop

```
echo '<a href="'.$media_url.$image_name.'" rel="lightbox['.$pid.']" title="Post: '.$pid.' |  '.$ptitle.' | Image: '.$image_name.' | by: '.$m_uname.' " ><img src="'.$thumb_path.$image_name.'" alt="'.$media->image_name.'" width="56" class="rm-thumbs-list" /></a>';
```

I have foreach loop and above code working fine with no issues. It is opening images in lightbox when the user clicks on the thumbnail. However now I have changed my mind. I am going to remove thumbnails and will add only one simple link when the user clicks on View Gallery I want to open lightbox with all the images

Comment: Could you post the generated functional HTML in jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `href` page , below `gallery.html` is page where all the image is stored.

```
<a href="gallery.html" rel="lightbox">View Gallery</a>
```

Comment: I am having loop so can't I use method/function instead of creating separate page?